# matplotlib basemap toolkit heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to follow this [example](https://github.com/kjordahl/SciPy2013/blob/master/examples/heatmap.py) which produces the following image:

[image]

When I tried to load my data I only get [image]

I know the problem lies with my data not being binary as commented in the example I'm using, but is that the only reason? I'm not sure how to convert it if it is the issue.

This is a small sample of my raw data. It's a `csv` format in `long,lat` format.

```
-122.425891675136,37.7745985956747
-122.425891675136,37.7745985956747
-122.42436302145,37.8004143219856
-122.42699532676599,37.80087263276921
-122.438737622757,37.771541172057795
-122.40325236121201,37.713430704116
-122.423326976668,37.7251380403778
-122.371274317441,37.7275640719518
-122.508194031117,37.776601260681204
-122.419087676747,37.8078015516515
-122.419087676747,37.8078015516515
-122.487983072777,37.737666654332706
-122.41241426358101,37.7830037964534
-122.432914603494,37.7843533426568
-122.397744427103,37.7299346936044
-122.38369150395901,37.7431890419965
-122.412597377187,37.783932027727296
-122.421681531572,37.7428222004845
-122.38640086995301,37.738983491072
-122.412249767634,37.782556330202
-122.449389111284,37.7426688025766
-122.420272135283,37.7473316298785
-122.412249767634,37.782556330202
-122.412249767634,37.782556330202
-122.43604920358601,37.79984122288229
-122.41050925879499,37.786043222299206
-122.43101755702699,37.7873880712241
-122.42365634294501,37.7325564882065
-122.475773497852,37.744919069591
-122.49978712068999,37.74851760347229
-122.431046366089,37.7830295716044
```

Comment: Your minimal complete code is needed to make your question useful. Two lines of data would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

When you read from a CSV file you get a list of strings. Supposing you have values `string_lon` and `string_lat`, use `float(string_lon)` and `float(string_lat)`.